# why my MapView don't display anything in fragment?

Tags: dictionary, fragment, android-mapview

I am trying to create sample android application that uses the MapView to display the map, but it didn't display anything in fragment.My MapFragment is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```